# Google documents overflow menu

Tags: android

Is there a way to create an overflow menu like the one inside google documents when you click the "three dots" icon of a document? I didn't find anything searching into the google documentation, maybe something in the google example github page?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the onOptionsItemSelected is triggered, try to implement Bottom sheets.

Here are the design guidelines - https://material.google.com/components/bottom-sheets.html

and check out the official article on the developer blog about bottom sheets (scroll down to read about Bottom sheets) - https://android-developers.blogspot.com/2016/02/android-support-library-232.html

Comment: Found another great guide to build your bottom sheet: [Bottom sheets guide](http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/how-to-use-bottom-sheets-with-the-design-support-library--cms-26031)